# how to know UIwebview is scrolling down side or up side? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, webview

in my app i am using small menu at the bottom of uiwebview. and i want to make like when user scroll downside that view must be hide. and when scrolling upside view must be unhide.
Like Safari.

this is what i tried

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("Going Down")
    viewbottom.hidden = true
    viewHieght.constant = 0
}



func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    print("Going Up")
    viewbottom.hidden = false
    viewHieght.constant = 45
}
```

but by using this code its continuously showing up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scroll view pan gesture recogniser to determine the direction.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview).y > 0 {
        // scrolls down
    } else {
        // scrolls up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep tracking the `scrollView.contentOffset.y` value and compare the last with the current value like so:

- in your mainView add:  `var lastScrollOffset = CGFloat()`
- compare the last value with the current one in `func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)`

  ```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
      if lastScrollOffset < scrollOffset{
          //scrolling down
      }else if lastScrollOffset > scrollOffset {
          //scrolling up
      }else{
          //going crazy
      }
      lastScrollOffset = scrollOffset
  }
  ```